# I removed a necessary constructor, yet it still compiles and runs

Tags: java

Whilst tidying up my project by removing what I believed to be unnecessary code, I removed a constructor of the form

```
public MyClass(int a,  int b)
```

leaving in place the other constructor

```
public MyClass(double c, double d)
```

There was a call to the int, int constructor which I hadn't noticed, yet it compiled and ran but invoked the double, double version, quite properly causing an exception handler I had written to be thrown. MyClass doesn't extend any other class.

By what rules does Java cause this invisible automatic cast to happen?

Comment: because an `int` value can be assigned to a `double` variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By this rule: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.2

It's a widening conversion.

Comment: Of course, you're correct. Somehow I had it in my head that it didn't apply to constructors which I thought were stricter on type checking - obviously not!

Answer (score 3):

This is a [**Widening Primitive Conversion**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.2). Since you can convert an `int` to a `double` without losing any information, the Java language performs this invisibly.

Answer (score 1):

In methods overloading, the most specific method is called, so if you have `foo(int, int)` and `foo(double, double)` and you call `foo(1,2)` then `foo (int, int)` will be called. but since 1, 2 may be doubles as well, if you don't have `foo(int, int)`, `foo(double, double)` will be called.